# REST API for Google access token from service account keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication, service-accounts

I have generated a service account keys from the google cloud console. Now I want a REST API where I can send the data of service account key data to retrieve the google JWT access token. How to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no prepared Google APIs for directly retrieving the access token from the Service account. So it is required to use the libraries for each language and/or the script created by each user. If you create the script, at first, the jwt is required to be created from client_email, private_key and scopes,  and then the access token is required to be retrieved with the created jwt. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Google OAuth Access Tokens are not JWTs. There is no REST API to call. There are HTTP endpoints where you can exchange a Signed JWT for an OAuth Access Token.

Comment: I wrote an article that shows the steps and Python source code. I recommend that you use Google client libraries. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike and John. I got one information from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#makingrequest
Here I am seeing that for passing grant_type and assertion to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
 it is returning the token. Can you please help me how to make the call? How to form the these two parameters?

Comment: You are referencing one article; I sent you a link for another. Both articles show you how. Invest the time to study how this is done, otherwise use the client libraries.

Comment: Yes @JohnHanley. I am going through with your code. It's really awesome. I have understood the process step by step. Thanks man.

Comment: @Dipankar Naskar Thank you for replying. I noticed that the discussions has already been advanced. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes @Tanaike. I got the solution. Thanks.